# face recognition using pca

Tags: face-recognition

In pca techniques after normalizing the eigenfaces, product of eigen faces are not coming orthogonal.
Because of this the weight of the image is not coming out proper.

I'm not able to proof the original image as a linear combination of eigen faces.

What could be the proper techniques?

Comment: There are a lot of websites out there talking about pca and ica for face recognition.  You will get sample code too. Please Google for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to reconstruct your face than you need that, but if you just want to recognize the face you dont need a linear combination of eigen faces.